# Storm upgrade - issue with zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

After upgrading from storm 0.9.1 to 0.9.2 I got the following exception while trying to run nimbus:

```
2014-06-29 16:31:47 b.s.d.nimbus [ERROR] Error when processing event
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: backtype.storm.daemon.common.SupervisorInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7648414326720210054, local class serialVersionUID = 7463898661547835557
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:93) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.cluster$maybe_deserialize.invoke(cluster.clj:200) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.cluster$mk_storm_cluster_state$reify__2284.supervisor_info(cluster.clj:299) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$all_supervisor_info$fn__4715.invoke(nimbus.clj:277) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at clojure.core$map$fn__4207.invoke(core.clj:2487) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:484) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$seq.invoke(core.clj:133) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$mapcat.doInvoke(core.clj:2514) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$all_supervisor_info.invoke(nimbus.clj:275) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$all_scheduling_slots.invoke(nimbus.clj:288) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$compute_new_topology__GT_executor__GT_node_PLUS_port.invoke(nimbus.clj:580) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$mk_assignments.doInvoke(nimbus.clj:660) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__5210$exec_fn__1396__auto____5211$fn__5216$fn__5217.invoke(nimbus.clj:905) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__5210$exec_fn__1396__auto____5211$fn__5216.invoke(nimbus.clj:904) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.timer$schedule_recurring$this__1134.invoke(timer.clj:99) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__1117$fn__1118.invoke(timer.clj:50) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at backtype.storm.timer$mk_timer$fn__1117.invoke(timer.clj:42) [storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: backtype.storm.daemon.common.SupervisorInfo; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7648414326720210054, local class serialVersionUID = 7463898661547835557
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:89) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
        ... 29 common frames omitted
2014-06-29 16:31:47 b.s.util [INFO] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
```

After killing QuorumPeerMain nimbus was able to run.
Looks like something is wrong with the zookeeper, or some traces from old zk versions are still cached somewhere.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: Having same problem with zk 3.4.4

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the reason why.

Quick solution : remove storm node recursively from your zookeeper and rerun.

Old data in zookeeper storm node conflicts with newly installed storm, and that causes serialVersionUID mismatch.

referred to 
https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/issues/27

Comment: link says nothing about zookeeper, and it would be more useful to put how to remove the node recursively in zookeeper than to instsruct to do it. this answer does not provide a solution

Comment: I faced this error - but in a different scenario. The same java.io.InvalidClassException (owing to mismatch in serialVersionUID) was showing up while submitting topology from the client m/c.The problem was that my version of Storm in the client side was different from what was running in the cluster.  The error went away after I directly submitted the topology from the nimbus m/c (or any other m/c in the cluster would have also worked fine) using the Storm binary installed there. I also referred : https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/issues/27